# mysql datetime field matching query not working correctly

Tags: mysql

I have written a mysql query

```
    select * from user where registration_date="2016-05-20"
```

But it returns wrong value. Please help me

Comment: What kind of value or error you are getting?

Comment: @Akash Khan Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please mark an answer that satisfies your question as correct

Comment: I was getting all values instead of only registered date is 20th may. But it has been fine now just adding date function @JayDoshi

Comment: Thanks to all who views this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
    select * from user where date(registration_date)=date("2016-05-20")
```